# What if there's a question here in a language other than English and Spanish?

Tags: discusión, idioma-de-la-publicación

There are many languages around the world and many people eager to learn Spanish; and not all of them are good in English.

What if we see a Chinese, Arabic, Persian, German, etc. question here asking about the Spanish language?

How should we respond?

Should we leave it in order to get answers from a native speaker or negatively vote for it?

How is it probable for the asker to get answers if their language is something other than English and Spanish?

Comment: The network [se] uses English and some sites, likes this one, allow their specific language. So a question in Spanish.SE posed in a language that is not Spanish or English should be closed as out of the scope of the site (no need to downvote, since those are for other things). See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All posts must be in either Spanish (preferred) or English (acceptable). All other languages are not permitted. This is explained [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), without explicitly stating that other languages are not permitted, though it is implicit.

This is also in line with the Stack Exchange policy across the entire network. Most sites allow only one language. The exceptions are a few that touch on linguistic topics (such as this one), and allow two. To my knowledge, there are none that allow three (or more) languages.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be preferable to politely ask the questioner if we can translate their question, assuming someone here were capable of doing so. The original question could be placed below a dividing line. The questioner would presumably be able to use an automatic translator to get a decent idea of the answers.